# CSS used in ofx.com

Tags: css

I'm trying to replicate css used in ofx.com (picture of London and a gray box with text), but mine doesn't work. I don't know what my code could be missing. Here's my code:

```
.generic-hero-blog {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f79e37;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.generic-hero--colour--grey {
    color: #fff;
}

.generic-hero--focus-center {
    background-position: center center;
}

.generic-hero--colour--grey .generic-hero--title {
    color: currentColor;
}

.generic-hero--container {
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 50px 15px 40px;
    text-align: center;
}




</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="generic-hero-blog generic-hero--colour--grey generic-hero--focus-center" style=" background-image:url(images/Harlem.jpg)">
                      <div class="generic-hero--container">
                      <h3 class=" generic-hero--title">Save with us now></h3>
                      </div>



                      </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain better what is not working? I just tested your code, and looks well: [Prntscr](http://prntscr.com/gsa1ma) and this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3n6kjbs3/)

Comment: @Zero The picture isn't in full scale and the gray box with text isn't showing (like that of ofx.com)

Comment: What is that `currentColor`?

Comment: @Zero gray (#464547)

Comment: Check this out now: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3n6kjbs3/)

Comment: @Zero Thanks mate, two things more, the gray box shouldn't span to both edge, it should be at the center. And also transparent. Thank you mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated @Zero's fiddle by adding a width to the container, centering it by setting the left and right margin values to `auto` and by giving it a grey, semi-transparent background:

```
.generic-hero--container {
  background: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.8);
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

See the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/andreasvirkus/3n6kjbs3/3/)

Comment: Thank you for reaching out mate